# How is the performance of complicated mysql triggers vs python code?

Tags: mysql, performance

My python application looks as follows:

```
def create_something(data):
    some_stuff
    insert_into_database(data)
```

Now the `some_stuff` is quite long and complicated, but can in principle be done by a mysql procedure. So I could also add a database `BEFORE INSERT` trigger and do all of it in the database directly.

The implementation difference is that right now that application is not stateless (stateful?), essentially because of the `some_stuff`. Putting all of this into the database procedure would allow me to make the application completely stateless, which I would like. But I wonder what the performance difference between these two options is?

Comment: Performance should be better, since it's fewer calls to the database.

Comment: But if you want to be sure, you have to benchmark it. There's no way to predict whether the MySQL stored procedure will be faster or slower than similar Python code.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the answer. Does the answer change if the function is more data-manipulation and computations, and only a limited amount of database calls?

Comment: Benchmark both and you will see. There really is no way to tell!

Comment: I don't understand why there is any difference in statelessness between the two approaches.

Answer (score 0):

- Fewer calls to the database is better -- especially if there is a long physical distance between client and server.
- Some algorithms are really messy to implement in SQL, hence your app language is better.
- Some algorithms are much more straightforward to implement in SQL, hence SQL is better.  Example:  A `JOIN` is 'better' than nested loops in the app.
- Using Triggers can obfuscate the code; keep this in mind when deciding whether to use them in SQL versus writing out more SQL statements.  Also, a Stored Procedure might be a clean way to express the code.
- "Cursors" in Stored Procs are horrible -- both in syntax and speed.
- A database is a repository for data, it is *not* a storage engine.  Do *not* expect to do all processing in SQL.
- A good interface (in this case, between SQL and your app) is a minimal one.  For example, summarize the data before returning only the aggregates, rather than shoveling lots of data to the app to summarize.